# Help needed coding an IRC client in Delphi 2010 using Indy Components

Tags: delphi, indy, irc

Im trying to code a basic irc client in Delphi 2010 using Indy components.
Im able to connect to my irc server (unrealircd) using sample A below.

After connecting I have many procedures that should perform actions when it receives a private message, ping, ctcp, channel modes etc. but they never react to any of these incoming events.

Sample A:
This connects to the IRC server when button4 is pressed.
It sucessfully joins the channel with the name specified.

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdIRC1.Host := '72.20.53.142';
  IdIRC1.Port := 6667;
  IdIRC1.Nickname := ssh.frmmain.Edit1.text;//insert your nickname here
    try
    idIRC1.Connect;
  except
    if not idIRC1.Connected then
      begin
        Memo2.Lines.add('Error Connecting to ' + idIRC1.Host);
        Exit;
      end;
  end;
  Memo2.Lines.add ('Connected to Auth Server');
  idIRC1.Join(channel,key);
  Memo2.Lines.add ('Auth Accepted');
end;
```

These events dont work at all and no errors are generated during a compile.

```
procedure TForm1.IdIRC1Connected(Sender: TObject);
begin
  memo2.Lines.Clear;
  memo2.Lines.add ('2Connected');
end;

procedure TForm1.IdIRC1ServerVersion(ASender: TIdContext; Version, Host, Comments: String);
begin
memo2.Lines.Add(Version +'Host '+Host+'Comments '+Comments);
end;
```

Comment: do you mean your event handlers are never invoked? make sure that they are associated to the events in the object.

Comment: the `OnConnected` event is guarateed to be fired if it has been assigned prior to calling Connect().  So I am with PA in assuming that your event handlers are not actually hooked up correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Ive had a few people look at this, and it just seems theres some unicode issues that destroyed my TClientSocket irc setup, and even when I moved to indy and used samples off the official site I was still unable to get anything to fire such as the onconnect event.

A friend had a copy of an application he wrote in Delphi 2010 using the same version of indy and I managed to import his project and it started working.

Not sure why